# MySQL - save JSON timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, json, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp given by a JSON. I want to push this into my database (MySQL). There is a row called "epoch" which is a date time type.

Printing the timestamp by the following code results in the correct result.

```
$epoch = date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $this->date);

echo "Timestamp: " . $this->date . " - Date: " . $epoch . "\n";
```

Timestamp: 1446746400 - Date: 05.11.2015 19:00:00

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO Forecast (epoch) VALUES ('" . $this->date . "')";
```

Result is a 0000-00-00 00:00:00 Date Value in my DB...

Can anybody explain me, how to pass this timestamp correctly into MySQL?

Comment: start by using a mysql date/time format: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html. there's no such thing as a "json timestamp". json has no real data types beyond primitive numerica/string/array/objects.

Comment: there is a TIMESTAMP data type in mySQL, what is the data type of your epoch column? SELECT column_name, data_type 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Forecast'

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$epoch_date = $epoch->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = "update forecast set epoch = '$epoch_date'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` format in mysql is not a timestamp like in php. You need to store a string that looks similar to your`$epoch` string:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->date)
```

would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL only accepts date in YYYY-MM-DD format. Anything other than this format will simply be discarded and the default value of the field is inserted as a result. So in order to store the correct date you need to convert it native datetime format of Mysql. You can use Mysql date_format() or php date function for this.